Django Admin - show a secondary table of related objects in the admin list view
I'm having a Django project which applies Admin pages only, i.e. no User pages at all.
I'm specifically applying the Admin-UnFold flavor, with a slightly enhanced UI.
Assume having 2 classes named AAA and BBB, where BBB has a ForeignKey named aaa.
( AAA may have multiple related BBBs )
Now, when listing the AAA instances, is it possible to maintain a secondary (new) table below the main one, which previews all related BBB objects for a selected AAA?
The selection may be achieved with a new designated column in the main table, with "preview" button/hyperlink.
From the user perspective (UI), clicking on the "preview" in the main table will allows a quick look on the corresponding related objects.
Thanks ahead,
Shahar

Hi maybe admin.TabularInline will help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline.

Thanks Mr.Teapot. I’m already using admin.TabularInLine and it’s indeed great. However, the request here is for a secondary “resources table” in the main list page.
